# Delphi Parallel For with custom threads

Tags: multithreading, delphi, localization, gettext, parallel.for

In our application, we have some scenarios where we use special LocalizedThreads to perform asynchronous tasks which need some kind of localization. They are used to simulate several features in other languages and to translate strings (via GNU GetText) into other users language.

Now, we had the case that we want to use [Delphi TParallel For loops](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Using_TParallel.For_from_the_Parallel_Programming_Library) in a function which may be called inside of a localized thread. This results in new threads, created by the PPL, inside which we lost the language context.

Example

```pascal
// this runs inside a localized thread
procedure DoSomething;
begin
// parallel for loop
  TParallel.For(Low, High, procedure(i: Integer)
    begin
      // do work
      _('Some required text to be translated.'); // calling thread from parallel for does not know   about localization context
    end;
  );
end;
```

Usually, the `_` function would get the target language via the CurrentThread (which is one of our a localized threads). However, inside the parallel loop, we have a new thread created.

What would be the best approach to keep the localization context inside the parallel for loop? Are there chances to pass custom thread class and set it´s language context correctly, for the parallel for loop?

Comment: You can use your own thread pool with TParallel-For loops. Just set each of those threads with the correct language context. Or utilize the option to pass an object where the language context can be defined and used within the loop. `TParallel.For(anObject,Low,High,etc)`.

Comment: I already tried the threadpool approach but the TThreadpool class in System.Threading is sealed, so I cannot inherit from it and implement the language feature. However, I will try your second idea to pass an additional object tomorrow and check if that will help.